# Registering WebAPI routes and its order - why it matters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I was playing around with ASP MVC and WebAPI and in Global.asax I've called a few pieces of code in following order:

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
WebApiConfig.Register(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

What these methods do is self-explanatory. But when I did registration in this order, I could not access Web API. However when I changed it to:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

then Web API started to work. So I assume that order of registration is important. But why?

Comment: Thanks for posting this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` before

`WebApiConfig.Register(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`

the default route for MVC is taking precedence and nothing ever makes it to the WebApi routes.

Answer (score 0):

I did some refactoring of my Global.asax to group MVC config and WebApi config together and just so happened to choose to do WebAPI config second.

Suddenly I started getting this kind of error for all of my API routes:

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /api/values
```

This issue was caused by the scenario that the original poster outlined.

**Always register your API routes first.**